# Google cloud account number

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity, service-accounts

what's the equivalent of AWS account number in Google cloud ?

If the user adds 2 service accounts to a portal, how to validate if the service accounts belong to different accounts or a single account.

Comment: As per documentation states, and I quote: "A service account is a special type of Google account that belongs to your application or a virtual machine (VM), instead of to an individual end user. Your application assumes the identity of the service account to call Google APIs, so that the users aren't directly involved. A service account can have zero or more pairs of service account keys, which are used to authenticate to Google." So answering your second question, service accounts do not belong to any account.
If you describe what you're trying to achieve I will be able to understand better.

Comment: I'm liking here the documentaiton where I found the info quoted above https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts

Comment: GCP service accounts are similar to AWS IAM roles. IAM roles have Amazon Resource Name(ARN) associated with it for identification. AWS account IDs are part of ARNs.  So if two IAM roles are added to a portal, it can be identified if they belong to same AWS account / different accounts by looking at the ARNs.  Is there something similar in GCP ?

Answer (score 0):

*AFAIK in GCP there's no account ID*.
By reading the AWS documentation looks like the concepts are slighty different in GCP and in AWS.
As I understand, you want to identify if a service account in GCP belongs to an account, the thing here *is that service accounts in GCP do not belong to any account.*

Quoting from [**the documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts):

> One of the features of IAM service accounts is that you can treat it both as a resource and as an identity.
>
> - When treating the **service account as an identity**, you can grant a
>     role to a service account, enabling it to access a resource (such as
>     a project).
> - When treating a **service account as a resource**, you can grant permission to a user to access that service account. You can grant
>     the Owner, Editor, Viewer, or Service Account User role to a user to
>     access the service account.

Example of how service accounts work in GCP as an identity:

> Let's say that I have 2 GCP projects where I am owner in both
>   projects:
>
> - projectA where I am owner with my email owner-of-project@gmail.com
> - projectB where I am owner with my email owner-of-project@gmail.com
>
> I log into projectA with owner-of-project@gmail.com and from there [**I  create a service account**](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts):
>
> - Service account name: service-account-project-A
> - Role of the service account (permissions): "Compute Engine Admin" (meaning that this service account will have only access to Compute    Engine resources within projectA).
> - Service account ID: service-account-project-a@projectA.iam.gservice
> - I can choose to generate a private key for this service account
> - I can also choose to enable [**G Suite Domain-wide Delegation**](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount?hl=en_US#delegatingauthority)
>
> Then I can log into projectB with owner-of-project@gmail.com. 
>   Once there I can add the [**service account**](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) as a member of projectB so the Compute Engine resources within project A will be reachable from projectB.

What you can do is **list all the service accounts** that are added **in a particular project** in the Service Accounts **section of GCP Console**.